# Ctrl + drag equivalent in Android Studio on Mac

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

In Android Studio (on Windows) if you select a text and then drag the text while holding Ctrl, the text gets duplicated and gets copied (instead of moved) to the place where you dropped.

What is the Mac equivalent of the same?

Just can't find an equivalent! I'm wondering if it even exists.

Comment: Did you try the Option (Alt) key?

Comment: I did, all of them, and all combinations too! No luck. :(